# Why is blender saying some of my scenes have no user

Tags: scene, data-blocks

Blender started "randomly" deleting some of my scenes and when I checked, it was because it said there are no users. I figured out how to add a fake user now (via the "Orphan Data" Outliner) but I'm still unsure why this is necessary.

Why would a scene require a user, and how can I make sure this doesn't happen in the future?

I also haven't found any pattern to which scenes are marked as having no users.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176758/how-do-i-fix-a-scene-with-zero-users

Comment: Exactly my issue.